# Custom routes with rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to get my application to show the url as follows: **example.com/42/jessica-alba**
This is my current routes line(not sure if it's correct)

```
match '/:id/:name' => 'models#show'
```

For some reason if I type example.com/42/gvkodjgj030 it'll still shw me the user with the id 42, regardless of the text after the /

Another thing I'm trying to accomplish is to get the link_to tags of the user to point to **example.com/42/jessica-alba** instead of **example.com/users/42**

Please help me out guys, this is my first rails app :)

****EDIT***: the first part is actually working with the snippet I've pasted, I still need to fix the 2nd part though.

Comment: Ask the second part of your question as a totally separate question, the two concepts you're wondering about are unrelated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in your routes.rb

```
  `match '/:id/:name' => 'models#show', :as => :show_model'
```

in your models/show.html.erb code,

```
  <%=link_to "Show", show_model_path(:id => 2, :name => "some name")
```

does that work?

Comment: can you run rake routes and tell me what route is generated for show_model_path?

Comment: @Felix you forgot the "link_to" part of the link_to :)

Comment: Hey Felix, I've posted the project on github: https://github.com/imjp/models

Here's the result of the rake routes: http://i.imgur.com/vVpFh.jpg

Comment: wow Felix, it worked! This is what the code should be(on the index page btw, not show)

`<%= link_to "show", show_model_path(:id => model.id, :name => model.name) %>`

Answer (score 3):

This is because all routing does is determine which action should handle the request. It doesn't do any of the processing.

Look in your `ModelsController` at the `show` action, and you'll see that the lookup is probably only using the `params[:id]` - if you want the lookup to depend on the `params[:name]` then the action is where you should change it.

Comment: Hey Gareth, mind helping me out in the RoR chat? I tried what you've said but it throws up a "Couldn't find Model without an ID" error