# Custom Method in Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I need to call a custom method in my controller from my Android app. I have a table name 'lists' which has multiple columns one of them being 'tableno'. I need to call a controller method which will fetch all the rows from lists table in DB for the passed table number and return it as JSON. In my app I will read the JSON. I have defined method in my lists controller as below:

```
def tableOrder
    @list = List.where(:tableno => params[:tableno])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @list }
    end
end
```

In my routes file I have given

```
resources :lists do
  member do
   get 'tableOrder'
  end
end
```

and the URL I am using to execute from my android app is `lists/tableOrder` with `get` method. The parameters I send from my Android app is a JSONObject: `jsonObject.put("tableno", tableNo);`. tableno here is the actual column name in my lists table.

The problem is its not executing the query and giving Missing template error. I checked the server and its not even reading the params I have sent. I am new to rails and writing such a thing for first time so not sure if I am missing something. Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Are you positive you want a member route? That is defining a route for `lists/:id/tableOrder`, but you say you want `lists/tableOrder`. What does this action do? In your action, you seem to want a single list. I am confused. Please explain.

Comment: can you please tell me is it showing missing template while you hit the url http://localhost:3000/lists/tableOrder ?

Comment: @RyanBigg yes that is also a wrong way of route define it should be `collection` instead of `member`

Comment: @RajarshiDas I checked and its giving blank page. Also I changed member to collection as suggested but still getting error Started GET "/lists/tableOrder" for 192.168.1.4 at 2013-09-04 09:54:25 +0530
  Processing by ListsController#tableOrder as HTML
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 0ms

Comment: @RyanBigg The actions need to select rows from my lists table based on tableno passed from my Android app. lists is the controller name.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554392/custom-routes-with-rails-3-1

Comment: @RahulGoutham Thanks for the link. I just tried the below suggested solution and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attempt to hit `lists/tableOrder.json` instead. The default format is .html, and that is why it is complaining that it cannot find a template.

Comment: Thanks Ryan. This worked. Its actually executing query in my method but unable to read JSONObject I sent.   Processing by ListsController#tableOrder as JSON
  List Load (60.0ms)  SELECT `lists`.* FROM `lists` WHERE `lists`.`tableno` IS NULL

Comment: How did you send this object? Why are you sending an object and not just a query parameter? (i.e. `/lists/tableOrder.json?tableno=1`)

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I was doing this incorrectly. Its working as you suggested. I tried the way my earlier query worked. There JSONObject was working fine in one of earlier cases. But in this its working as you suggested. Thanks again for everything.